# Filter a dataframe based on combination of columns from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I am currently working on a data analytics project for the organisation I am interning at, to analyse connection logs from network traffic. A requirement is to create a filter file which would contain some internally approved IPs and ports(like antivirus, sys admin, etc), and these should be filtered out from the main logs file before processing.
The filter file is a .txt file with JSON object lines and each line consists of Source_IP, Destination_IP and Destination_Port. And each of the lines can have entries where any combination of the columns are filled/empty, and it can have all 3 columns empty too. The sample log entries and filters are as belows -

[Sample connection log entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj3XX.png)

[Sample filter file lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6sRB.png)

What I need is that filter file is used to remove entries from the main log files. In the first filter file, all 3 are filled so it would remove all entries pertaining to those triplet values. In the 2nd line, only Source_IP and destination_IP are filled, and destination_port is empty. So, it would remove all entries with that particular pair of (source_IP,destination_IP) irrespective of ports. And in the 3rd line, only source_IP is specified so it would remove all entries where source_IP is as specified, irrespective of destination IP and port.

When I convert the filter file to a dataframe, there and empty cells and I fill with them 0, using `df.replace("",0)` and then used `df.isin()` function. In the filter file, I have used the 1st log, 3rd log(only source IP and destination IP), 5th log(only source IP), most connected source IP, and 2nd last log entry (only destination IP and destination port).

```
df = pd.read_json('file',lines=True)
df_filter = pd.read_json('filter', lines=True)
df.isin(df_filter)
```

[Filter lines as specified above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNQf0.png)

When I execute it, it only works on the first log and remaining everything is false.

[Only 1st log has been affected. The 3rd,5th and 2nd last log are unaffected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhQSF.png)

But when I use the first 3 consecutive log entries(1st log with all 3 columns, 2nd log with source IP and destination IP, and 3rd with only source IP) -
[First 3 consecutive log entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK53J.png)

it works as desired and I am able to identify and drop them -

[It works on the top 3 logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dq3M.png)

I want it to work as it does with the 3 consecutive entries but with any entries specified, but it is not working that way as specified in the first paragraph.